Creating a Leaderboard
Attempting to create a high score table with saving and loading using serialization/deserialization approach. My code below compares the current accumulated score and loaded player score (if any).
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> targets;
    
    // status of game
    public bool gameIsActive;
    public bool gameLost;
    public bool gameComplete;

    private float spawnRate = 3.0f;

    // data variables
    public int score;
    public string playerName;

    // high score user info 
    public string bestPlayer;
    public int bestScore;

    // Audio clips for different scenarios
    public AudioClip mainSound;
    public AudioClip gameSound;
    
    // creating instance
    public static GameManager Instance;

    // timer duration
    public float timerCountdown;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance != null)
        { 
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        Instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        LoadData();
        // Play the main menu sound
        AudioManager.Instance.PlaySound(mainSound, 1f);
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (gameIsActive)
        {
            UpdateTimer();
        }
    }
    private void UpdateTimer()
    {
        if (timerCountdown > 0)
        {
            timerCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
            timerCountdown = Mathf.Max(timerCountdown, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            EndGame();
        }
    }

    public void SubmitName(string args)
    {
        playerName = args;
        Debug.Log("Player " + playerName + " has been submitted:");
    }

    public void GameStart(int setLevel)
    {
        gameIsActive = true;
        timerCountdown = 15f;
        gameComplete = false;
        gameLost = false;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        score = 0;
        spawnRate /= setLevel;
        // Play the game sound
        AudioManager.Instance.PlaySound(gameSound, 0.05f);

        StartCoroutine(SpawnTargets());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnTargets()
    {
        while (gameIsActive)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnRate);
            
            int indexCount = Random.Range(0, targets.Count);
            Instantiate(targets[indexCount]);
            
        }
    }
    public void EndGame()
    {
        gameIsActive = false;
        if (score < 0)
        {
            gameLost = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            gameComplete = true;
        }

        StartCoroutine(RestartGame());
    }

    IEnumerator RestartGame()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
    }

    public void IncreaseScore(int pointValue)
    {
        score += pointValue;
    }

    public void DecreaseScore(int pointValue)
    {
        score -= pointValue;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    class SaveData
    {
        public int bestScore;
        public string bestPlayer; 
    }

    public void SaveBest(int score, string playerName)
    { 
        SaveData saveData = new SaveData();
        saveData.bestScore = score;
        saveData.bestPlayer = playerName;


        // transform instance to JSON
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveData);

        try
        {
            // write string to a file
            File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savefile.json", json);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning($"Failed to save data: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
    public void LoadData()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/savefile.json";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        { 
            string json = File.ReadAllText(path);

            SaveData data = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveData>(json);

            bestScore = data.bestScore;
            bestPlayer = data.bestPlayer;
        }
    }
}

using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LeaderboardUIHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI playerBestText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreBestText;

    public Button continueButton;
    private string starterScene = "Starter";

    private void Awake()
    {
        GameManager.Instance.LoadData();
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Debug.Log("Player Name: " + GameManager.Instance.bestPlayer);
        //Debug.Log("Player Score: " + GameManager.Instance.bestScore);
        continueButton.onClick.AddListener(LoadStarter);
        CheckBestPlayer();
    }

    void CheckBestPlayer()
    {
        if (GameManager.Instance.score > GameManager.Instance.bestScore)
        {
            GameManager.Instance.bestScore = GameManager.Instance.score;
            GameManager.Instance.bestPlayer = GameManager.Instance.playerName;

            GameManager.Instance.SaveBest(GameManager.Instance.bestScore, GameManager.Instance.bestPlayer);
            playerBestText.text = $"Best Player: {GameManager.Instance.bestPlayer}";
            scoreBestText.text = $"Best Score: {GameManager.Instance.bestScore}";
            Debug.Log("Best Player Name: " + GameManager.Instance.bestPlayer);
            Debug.Log("Best Player Score: " + GameManager.Instance.bestScore);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Player " + GameManager.Instance.playerName + " wasn't able to beat high score");
            DisplayBestPlayer();
        }
    }

    private void DisplayBestPlayer()
    {
        //Debug.Log($"Player Name: {GameManager.Instance.bestPlayer}");
        playerBestText.text = $"Player Name: {GameManager.Instance.bestPlayer}";
        Debug.Log("Loaded " + GameManager.Instance.bestPlayer + "'s score: " + GameManager.Instance.bestScore);
        //Debug.Log($"Player Score: {GameManager.Instance.bestScore}");
        scoreBestText.text = $"Player Score: {GameManager.Instance.bestScore}";
    }

    void LoadStarter()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(starterScene);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```


What is your question? Is there something this code is not doing that you'd like help implementing, or something it shouldn't be doing that you'd like help fixing?
